# When salivary amylase breaks down starch, are those substances tagged or destined for a particular use in the body

Tags: digestion

When salivary amylase breaks down starch, are those substances identified for a particular use in the body?

Answer (score 2):

Salivary amylase breaks starches brown into shorter chain of sugars. In the beginning of the small intestine, this process is continued by pancreatic amylase. Other enzymes at the surface of the intestine's lining complete the process resulting in simple sugars which absorbed into the circulatory system. Some of these sugars, if there is an excess in your diet, will be converted to fat and stored.

The rest of the sugars will ultimately be taken into cells and undergo a process termed cellular respiration. The bulk of these sugars will be broken down and used to create (recharge actually) ATP, a substance that just about any process in the cell requiring energy can use for energy. The atoms in the sugars used in this process end up as carbon dioxide, which you breath out, and water. But a certain percentage of the sugars only get partially broken down. These fragments can be used to synthesize many different substances depending on what's needed in the cell at that time.